# Tethering using a Nokia N8-00

Tags: wireless-networking, remote-access, hotspot, tethering

My trusty old ZTE Android wich I used as an wireless access point for my computers was stolen the day before yesterday... I have a Nokia N8-00 but it seems to be really flaky... I had to d/l an app to get basic internet connectivity tethering working, but lot's of sites using https fail miserably. I'm kindof out of options here... Does anybody know if upgrading to the premium version of JoikuSpot solves these problem? Or if it is possible to somehow use USB tethering on the N8-00.

Are there outher options? I'm thinking some kind of wireless router that I can fill cash for GB...

Edit: I just realized that JoikuSpot works with Windows 7, but Ubuntu 14.04 gives me all kinds of problem...

Comment: Can the Nokia do WiFi hotspot?

Comment: It can, but the results are really flaky in Ubuntu 14.04. Facebook and other https heavy sites fail

Comment: According to other forums if you put the phone's USB connection into "PC Suite" (or something to do with Ovi mode?) Then Ubuntu should pick it up (drivers for the modem type are in the kernel) and you can add a broadband connection using the network manager...

Comment: The forum says Ubuntu 10 but it should work for later. http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1796280

Answer (score 1):

I have a Nokia N8 as well and looked in vain for something like tethering on the phone itself. My Sony Android had such a feature. I looked for mobile hotspot...nothing.
Now I know I had to look for a way to create an new obile broadband connection on the PC.

I know the way to do it in Linux Voyager X2 (combi Ubuntu-Debian).
Itś very easy.
Just plug the N8 in via USB cable.
Evt. you have to unlock your phone. I did, before Linux / Windows actually recognises the phone.
Than, you go to Network Manager of search for Network Connections.
Choose Add  / New Mobile Broadband
Choose provider and Create and that´s it.
Evt. you have to Enable Mobile Broadband ( in my case T-Mobile)
Otherwise you can pick your newly created mobile broadband from the dropdown menu.